# PDO loop call function only one time

Tags: php, loops

In my code i have a for loop and inside the loop I call another function. the loop executes 3 times but the function inside the loop only calls one time. below the code CreateItemInfo() function call only one time but it supposes to call 3 times since the size of $s is 3.any idea how can I fix it

```
if($order->CreateOrderInfo()){

    echo 'Order created successfully.';
    echo "---";
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($s); $i++){
        $order->ItemCode = $s[$i];
        $order->GetItemInfo();
    
        if ($order->ItemCode != null){
            $item_array = array(
                'UserMememberNo' => $order->UserMememberNo,
                'Image' => $order->Image,
                'Description' => $order->Description,
                'Price' => $order->Price,
                'ItemBrand' => $order->ItemBrand,
                'ItemModel' => $order->ItemModel
            );

            $order->ItemGUID = $data->ItemGUID;
            $order->ItemName = $order->Description;
            $order->ItemPrice = $order->Price;

            if($order->CreateItemInfo()){
                echo 'Item created';
            }else{
                echo 'Unable to create item';
            }

            echo json_encode($item_array);
        }else{
            echo json_encode('No item Found');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sure that 'if ($ order-> ItemCode! = Null)' is 3 times different from NULL ???

Comment: Which method only executes once? And what are the contents of `$s` (like `print_r($s)`) before you begin this loop?

Comment: As an aside, C-style incrementing for loops are pretty uncommon in PHP, and it is usually recommended to use `foreach ($s as $value)` - inside the loop then use `$value` in place of `$s[$i]` since you are not using the counter `$i` elsewhere.